# Compartir Conexión Datos Externos Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo un archivo Excel 365 con una tabla conectada a una Base de Datos (SQL Server) para traer información. Tiene como autenticación un usuario y contraseña con privilegios de Solo Lectura.

Quiero compartir el archivo y que los usuarios puedan actualizar la tabla sin estar colocando de manera manual el usuario y contraseña para la Base de Datos. Como puedo incluirla en el archivo para no proporcionarla?

Gracias, Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira en [Crear, editar y administrar conexiones a datos externos](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/crear-editar-y-administrar-conexiones-a-datos-externos-89d44137-f18d-49cf-953d-d22a2eea2d46) para exportar la conexión a ver si cuela.

Comment: Gracias, si funciona ! Aunque debe ser archivo de conexión por archivo aunque pertenezca a la misma base de datos.